# jQuery floating header strangeness

Tags: jquery

I'm using a jQuery floating header.

The following classes are from my stylesheet:

```
.sorting_asc {
    background: url('../images/arrow2_n.gif') no-repeat center right;
}
.sorting_desc {
    background: url('../images/arrow2_s.gif') no-repeat center right;
}
.sorting {
    background: url('../images/arrow_updown.gif') no-repeat center right;
}
```

I simply override this code using style tags in one of my views to say `background-image:none`.  On the page, the table displays correctly.  However, the floating header reverts to the CSS defined in the stylesheet.  Why is this?

Comment: Can you link to the page with this problem, or post a demo that reproduces the problem at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely a specificity issue.  Your overriding selector needs to be more specific to take over any previously declared rules.  Or the rule must have an `!important`